# How strong is Hawkeye?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Near the end of *Avengers: Endgame*, Hawkeye just

> answered a phone call from his wife when Thanos' ship appears over the Avengers' base and launches a ton of missiles. The first missile appears to land maybe 5ft in front of Hawkeye.

Does he have other super powers aside from quick reflexes? I don't see how he came away from that

> (plus the fall through quite a few floors of broken concrete and steel)

without just a bit of dust on him.

Comment: He's imbued with *plot-armour*.

Comment: Not very strong.

Answer (score 3):

He has [peak human](https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Peak_Human_Condition) strength.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkeye_(comics)):

> While Hawkeye has no superhuman powers (with the exception of the period when using [Pym particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Pym) to become Goliath), he is at the very peak of human conditioning. He is an exceptional fencer, acrobat and marksman, having been trained from childhood in the circus and by the criminals [Trick Shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trick_Shot_(comics)) and [Swordsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swordsman_(comics)#Jacques_Duquesne). This includes considerable strength, as an employee of Cross Technological Enterprises found out when he tried to use the superhero's 250 [pounds-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(force)) (1,100 [newtons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_(unit))) draw-weight bow and found that he could not draw back the string to launch an arrow.

From [Marvel.com](https://www.marvel.com/characters/hawkeye-clint-barton/on-screen/profile):

> An expert acrobat and military-trained combatant with exceptional endurance, stamina, and agility, Barton can stand to-to-toe with some of the best fighters around.

[Marvel.com](https://www.marvel.com/characters/hawkeye-clint-barton/in-comics) also gives him a rating of **2** for strength.

Answer (score 1):

No, he doesn't have any other super powers, it was just good luck, I guess.